# I Changed The Name Of The Folder My Project Was In And Now Xcode Cannot Find My Project

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am using xcode 4. I simply changed the name of the physical folder all the files for my project are now when I click on the project file and open it in xcode ITS GONE! xcode is not letting me launch the project now. Please help!

Comment: I got it back by changing the folder name back to what it was before, but where am I suppose to change the physical folder name if I wanna change the name?

Comment: Is this the outermost folder containing your project as a whole, or an inner folder containing project files?

Comment: Yeah this is the outermost folder containing the project as a whole

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Go to the folder, click on the project file. If the files are red or not there, add them back. That should be enough. Otherwise, if there is any error message, post it. Changing a project folder name is not enough to screw up a project, so I guess you did something else.

Comment: when I open the folder and click the project file, xcode opens and only shows the name of the project file in red.

Comment: That's unusual and I don't have a solution. It means it's not able to find/understand the project file. Try creating a different project, copying all the files to it, and add them back. It's a drag but it should work. If you right click the project file, there should be a text project.pbxproj file, which is the only thing you need for the project to work. Something must be wrong there.

Comment: I can't "add back" files inside of en.lproj folder (which is a sub-folder of the project files folder), which are always in red